# Android: last card of RecyclerView cut off. Can't scroll any further. Why would this happen?

Tags: android

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:

[image]

For some reason, the last card of the RecyclerView is not showing up properly. This is a weird occurrence especially since the RecyclerView is just wrapping content.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Why might something like this occur? How can I make it so that the RecyclerView is not cut off?

Comment: This usually happens with wrap_content. have you tried `match_parent` ?

Comment: Is this a bug with wrap_content? I will try match_parent and see what happens. Thanks for the suggestion. EDIT: Just tried it and it fixed the problem. Thanks poss!

Comment: have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item/60314197#60314197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by poss: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4048794/poss

choosing wrap_content as the attribute for layout_width and layout_height causes the cut-off on RecyclerViews

Comment: so what should it be put to ??

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada use match_parent. Just tried it and it worked. See comment of poss above.

Comment: @EmanuelSeidinger I am using padding which is not a solution. will be helpful if you can share the source. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView cannot have WRAP_CONTENT as layout_height.
The solution is to set layout_height to a specific value like "100dp", like the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    ...
/>
```

Now if the value in the xml is not what you want, you can set layout_height in the code using requestLayout();

Answer (score 1):

I have a RecyclerView similar to Marcin Orlowski's.
Now it works for me after I applied the solution of setting the height of layout_height in Java using requestLayout.
It cannot be set in onCreate method, however.  It needs to be set in onWindowFocusChanged method.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int[] loc = new int[2];
    recyclerView.getLocationOnScreen(loc); // get the location of the recyclerview
    int distance_to_bottom = dm.heightPixels - loc[1]; // similar to Marcin's design
    // RecyclerView 直到版面的最下端
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = distance_to_bottom;
    recyclerView.requestLayout(); // set it right here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.Then i try to add some space in the bottom of the recyclerview. If you try all the above solutions and still got the issue, then try this one.

add

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to your recyclerview code . like this

```
<RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/my_rv"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="10dp"
 android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me, so I just added three main inside my recycler View:

1. First of all, give your recycler View height and width as: **match parent**
2. Secondly give bottom padding, as paddingBottom = "10dp"
3. Include, clipToPadding = "false"

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/postRV"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
   android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

Answer (score 0):

If you have an header above the RecyclerView, setting

```
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

is not a good choice, because the RecyclerView will overlap with the header.

This can be solved by setting, as someone already said, layout_height attribute to a fixed value, like

```
        android:layout_height="300dp"
```