# How to remove extra space in Card View above

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

There is an extra space in CardView ....I have tried to remove the linear layout above it but tht is distorting the content in it n fitsSystemWindows attributte also doesn't work.

n it is there for both Pre and Post lollipop versions

[image: space over card view]

```
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ListView
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/messages_list"
        android:layout_weight="100"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:divider="@null"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/linearsend"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="#c8ffffff">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageSimly"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mood_24dp"/>
                <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
                    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apklib/hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText"
                    android:id="@+id/new_messagee"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#778BB0"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
                    android:hint="type a message..."
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    emojicon:emojiconSize="20sp" />
                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:id="@+id/fabSend"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_24dp"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from LinearLayout? How does it look?

Comment: ya after that if i want to write something in editText the Box doesnt show up above the keyboard ... n thts why I putted tht attribute

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item

Comment: thnks but its not working

Comment: @SahajRana is their any reason to put fix width for `EmojiconEditText` in your layout  as it is given `250dp` rather make it `Wrap Content`?

Comment: ya because without it the content in card view were coming out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If SomeBody Finds Better Solution Please Notify**

So, I have a temperory solution to it.. as told by @Jay Patel, I got an idea and 
set the outermost layout to frame layout as the space i think is due to list view,
N (I haven't set any margin bottom)

So, the code is..

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/messages_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/linearsend"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="#c8ffffff">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageSimly"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mood_24dp"/>
                <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
                    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apklib/hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText"
                    android:id="@+id/new_messagee"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#778BB0"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
                    android:hint="type a message..."
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    emojicon:emojiconSize="20sp" />
                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:id="@+id/fabSend"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_24dp"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in XML file

**xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
card_view:contentPadding="-3dp"**

also add below line but it is optional but usable in Card View

**card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"**

Comment: `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` will remove corner radius...n `card_view:contentPadding="-3dp"` is only moving the content inside card view not the space above it

Comment: Please put below code and Check it

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                card_view:contentPadding="-3dp">

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ListView
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/messages_list"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:divider="@null"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/linearsend"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="#c8ffffff">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageSimly"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mood_24dp"/>
                <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
                    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apklib/hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText"
                    android:id="@+id/new_messagee"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#778BB0"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
                    android:hint="type a message..."
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    emojicon:emojiconSize="20sp" />
                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:id="@+id/fabSend"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_24dp"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```