# TextView - detect if String exceeds available space

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout

```
         RelativeLayout
             ImageView  iv1
             TextView  
                   toTheRightOf iv1
                   toTheEndOf   iv1
                   toTheLeftOf  iv2      
             ImageView  iv2
         RelativeLayout end
```

So TextView is sandwiched between two ImageViews. So everything is displaying exactly as it should. However sometimes the line in the TextView is too long and comes too close to second ImageView. Sometimes extending right into it.  I am not looking to change the layout or try to squeeze around anything.  What I want to do is detect when the length of the String is too long and change the content of the String to abbreviated version with fewer characters.  How can I tell if and when the String is too close to the ImageView? Sometimes there is room and sometimes not. This layout is for item in a RecyclerView - not that that really matters much as far as the question is concerned.  I know Android can detect when String is too long and add ... but what I am trying to do is rather than ... I want to simply change the String to one that has fewer characters.

Perhaps I just need to decide how many characters is too many? But will this change by device resolution etc? Or will it be the same whether I am on a tablet or Galaxy Note, or smaller device?  I don't want a different layout per device just for this issue. I would rather just dynamically be able to check whether the string will take up too much room. In any event it's not really a layout change it's a string content change I am after.

UPDATE: TO CLARIFY.

Let's say the String is 'Thursday, December 19, 2017'
If this is would take up too much room then I don't want to see
    'Thursday, December 19 ...'
Rather I want to see that the String is too long and instead do

```
    tv.setText('12/19/2017');
```

I want to conditionally set the text value based on whether the given string takes up too much room.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dsajkhfkjhfasa fbsa fas fahj afs fsa afs sf afs sda da das dsals"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout, textview would ellipsize itself whenever the length would be greater than the available space.

Comment: I have updated my question. ellipse is usually best but not for my use case.  For example let's day the string is 'Thursday, December 28th, 2017'  I don't want 'Thursday, Dec ..." rather I want 'Th, 12/28/2017'

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful. I did something like that, and in my solution I am scaling down textView, but you can set shorter text.

```
    if(textView.getWidth() > 0) {
        float widthOfTheText = textView.getPaint().measureText(textView.getText());
        if(widthOfTheText > textView.getWidth()) {
            //exceeds, let scale it
            textView.setTextScaleX((textView.getWidth()-0.1f)/widthOfTheText);
        } else {
            //not exceeds
        }
    } else {
        //not layouted yet
        textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
              TextView tv = (TextView) v;
              float widthOfTheText = tv.getPaint().measureText(tv.getText());
              tv.setTextScaleX((tv.getWidth()-0.1f)/widthOfTheText);
              tv.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

              if(widthOfTheText > tv.getWidth()) {
                 //exceeds, let scale it
                 tv.setTextScaleX((textView.getWidth()-0.1f)/widthOfTheText);
              } else {
                 //not exceeds
              }
           }
       });
    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I am going to try this and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I set a spannable for the text and as this is char sequence it says that textView.getPaint().measureText(..) cannot be used ...

Comment: For spannable `CharSequence` check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613819/2318843

Comment: Yes, I am getting that. However issue is layout is Item in RecycleView. in onBindViewHolder()  they layout overall has not been measured yet ... This is the point where I am setting the Text.

Comment: I have changed the code. It should work, of course you should refactor it, there are two similar block of code which could be extracted to separate function.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this exact code. The problem is that it always determines it is not too long.  The width using the technique you described above produces width of 159 to 169 for the Scannable.  At 159 there is no truncation. At 169 there is a truncation. The width of the TextView is always about 304 so it always passes ... Not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Do you have any padding applied to TextView? If yes you should subtract it from views width

Comment: I doubt there is over 100 in padding.  I will probably check this. What I am now doing is setting lines="2" then checking in the listener if the second line has any characters in it. If there are characters then I apply the text size change or scaling change until there is nothing spilling over into the second line. So far this seems to work.