# TextView how can I get Text that is actually rendered?

Tags: android, android-layout

Sometimes text String get's truncated or eclipsed when it is too long to fit. 
How can I detect when this has happened and also get the exact String that is rendered vs. requested to be rendered?
Ellipse is not always drawn. Stop asking about content stupid editor. There is lots of content and you are not formatting the code at all now!

```
final ViewTreeObserver obs = viewHolder.myTextView.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {   

     @Override  
     public void onGlobalLayout() {      
          Layout l = viewHolder.myTextView.getLayout();      
          if (l != null) {            
              int lines = l.getLineCount();             
              if ( lines > 0 ) {               
                  if (l.getEllipsisCount(lines-1) > 0) {                   
                      LazLog.d(PaginatorAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Text is ellipsized");        
                  }    
              }
           }
     });
```

Sometimes text String get's truncated or eclipsed when it is too long to fit. How can I detect when this has happened and also get the exact String that is rendered vs. requested to be rendered?  Ellipse is not always drawn. Stop asking about content STUPID STACK OVERFLOW editor. There is lots of content and you are not formatting the code at all now! I have pushed it over more than a tap space and it's not recognising it as code. Someone please edit and tell me what I supposedly did wrong here????

Answer (score 0):

Well you certainly can get ellipsized (not eclipsed) text of your `TextView`:

```
String text = (String) textView.getText().subSequence(textView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart(0), textView.getText().length());
```

Comment: This will crash if the text is a scannable.  Here is more what is happening:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243141/textview-detect-if-string-exceeds-available-space    I am trying to detect when the string is too long.  So far it just truncates the spannable and leaves off the last half. It also does not do and ellipse.

Comment: What if it truncates instead?  I want a method that returns me the String that is rendered.  The whole string as opposed to whatever it was passed in during setText(spannable)

Comment: no @moritzg it's not going to work because there is sometimes truncation without an ellipse. And in this case I don't think this will provide the actual string. Sometimes you get truncations rather than ellipses when lines are too long or whole words get truncated. Be sure the vote up the question since you took the time to answer it. thanks