# RecyclerView (wrap_content) inside of a BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I'm facing a tricky situation here and I don't know how to solve this problem.
In my project I have a custom `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and in the layout a `FrameLayout` to add or replace `Fragment`s.

Now I have a `Fragment` and inside I have a `RecyclerView` with the `height:="wrap_content"` because I want the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` only use the necessary space. Everything looks great, the problem appear when I put another view inside of the same layout and set the `RecyclerView` bellow or above of that view.
The `RecyclerView` ignores the size of the other view (or views) and always grows to the max screen size, and then it's no possible to see a few elements and even scroll.

I saw a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item), some developers are suggesting to add `paddingBottom` equals to the height of the view. But in my case doesn't works because I want to have a dynamic solution.

Above I'll share a few images of the problem and [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/extmkv/RecyclewViewBottomSheetExample) with a sample.

[image]
[image]
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Well, this is a typical situation.. Are all your items dynamically added?

Comment: No, but I have a lot of  `fragment`s, different layouts with a few recycleviews

Comment: According to my understanding, you need to first get the area of the parent view where the items are added.. depending on that you can manipulate.

Comment: try using LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout!

Comment: @xbadal I already tried with LinearLayout and Constraint without success

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've manage to do what you need just need to use this as your **fragment_sample.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rclItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddMoreItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rclItems"
    android:text="@string/add_1_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Explanation*
Using a LinearLayout gives you the ability to work with weight, and the vertical orientation allows you to place an item below the other. The weight on the recyclerview will increase the height of it as needed until filling the screen. The next item you add would be added to the recyclerview but you'll need to scroll the list to see it

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I still confusing... do you know why work in this way and not with `wrap_content` inside of a `ReleativeLayout` or in a `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Yes, because with relative or constraint the button will always be below the recyclerview. So if it has 100 records below the 100th will be the button. The way I propose you, you are forcing the button to be visible and let the recycler view expand as mush as needed, until reaching the screen height. Then it could still grow but as the button is always visible, you will need to scroll the recycler to view them. That's how the **weight** works

Comment: Yes, make all the sense @sebasira! Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @sebasira I don't know why the hell but this works perfectly and fixes all the issues that we had with `RecyclerView` in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Only with Android, you can fix a bunch of issues by only replacing the parent layout :)

Comment: The permanent and latest solution as of today is this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591005/5471183

Answer (score -5):

The android developers blog says that :-

> The scrolling containers in your bottom sheet must support nested scrolling .

Try changing your `fragment_sample.xml` as below to make the `recyclerview` scroll working and to make  the add button persistent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/next"
 android:layout_above="@id/btnAddMoreItems"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rclItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddMoreItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_1_item"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note**:  making bottomsheet layout a child view of `CoordinatorLayout` will allow you to get the implement BottomSheetBehavior  and recieve its transitions callbacks .

Comment: Don't put RecyclerView into a scroll view. RecyclerView supports nested scrolling. `The android developers blog says` Always post a link to back up your claims.