# RecyclerView obscurs items below it in a BottomSheetFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I'm using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with a custom layout. I'm trying to have the following setup:

```
<TextView> -> pinned to the top of the bottom sheet
<RecyclerView> -> wrap_content 
<Button> -> pinned to the bottom of the bottom sheet
```

Both `TextView` and `Button` must be visible at all time (sticky), while the `RecyclerView` should stay in the middle and scroll without obscuring other views.

This is my layout so far:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what it looks like with a small list of items, where the `RecyclerView` has no need to scroll.

[image]

This is what it looks like with a large list of items.
The title stays pinned to the top, but the button doesn't.
The button is actually not even visible, even if I scroll down all the way.

[image]

What's strange to me is that this same layout works with a regular full screen activity, but it somehow fails with a `BottomSheetFragment`.

I've already looked at other posts, but none of them helped e.g.

- [RecyclerView (wrap_content) inside of a BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187908/recyclerview-wrap-content-inside-of-a-bottomsheetdialogfragment)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out to be an issue with the bottom sheet state configuration and not the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up being the solution is setting the state of bottom sheet to expanded e.g.

```
val bottomSheetDialog = requireDialog() as BottomSheetDialog
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

I suppose that the bottom sheet never expanded fully, so the layout was never fully visible. I thought that the bottom sheet would expand automatically based on the height of the content, but I was wrong. The layout itself is fine, I didn't have to make any changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

The height of recycler view shouldn't be wrap_content

If you want recyler in-between your title and footer, the better approach is set height = 0 and pin its top to the bottom title and its bottom to the top of footer (like you already did), it will auto stretch for you

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. The `RecyclerView` gets squashed between the two and it's not visible at all.

Answer (score -1):

To correct this behavior of recyclerview, put below property in your recyclerview layout.

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

Also change your parent constraint layout height to wrap content like below :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
```

Comment: Height if rv should never be wrap_content as it will disable view recycling

Comment: I didn't mentioned to change RV height @JazibKhan . Please check before rating negative to any answer.