# Bottom item cut in reyclerview in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

Hey I am working in constraint layout with recylerview. My bottom item is cut in the screen. I read this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32742724/18958467). I don't want to use relative layout or linear layout. Can someone guide me how to fix this in constraint layout.

**abc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreScroll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/exploreScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/exploreChips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipSpacingHorizontal="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/exploreList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exploreScroll" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My view cut from

[image]

UPDATE

@Zain after your suggestion i tried in my xml any my `HorizontalScrollView` is going behind my `RV`. I am adding my blueprint and you can see clearly that, `HorizontalScrollView` is going behind. After removing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreList" from the HorizontalScrollView`.

[image]

2nd suggestion try

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer  Using a `wrap_content` height with vertical `RecyclerView`
> can have impact on performance in terms of recycling views; specially
> if the height is going to change frequently. Check [this article](https://medium.com/android-news/android-dev-tip-4-91b7757b1f0a)
> for more illustration.

So, the first step is to designate the `RecyclerView` height or to constraint it; from the constraints you want it to expand to the bottom; so use `0dp` for that. But in order to make the minimum height to wrap content of the `RecyclerView` (in case that the items don't exceed the screen height); you can set the default height constraint to wrap with `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` constraint.

Then remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreList"` from the `HorizontalScrollView`, this actually made the bottom item of the RV hide (your main issue); because it is an over-constraint; the `HorizontalScrollView` tends to push the `RV` to the bottom while the `RV` tends to push the `HorizontalScrollView` to the top.

This will solve the main issue; but when the items are fully accommodated by the screen (no scrolling in the RV), then it will be biased in the middle; to fix this use the bias with `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"` to be biased to the top.

Adding this in place into the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreScroll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/exploreScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/exploreChips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipSpacingHorizontal="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/exploreList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exploreScroll" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Zain I tried your solution, but I am getting problem in my code. Can you please check `UPDATE` section in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @vivekmodi Thanks for your notification; you're right; I updated it now; the problem that we need to use the default height constraint instead of the minimum one; and also added the bias to move the RV contents to the top. please have a look .. all the changes in the RecyclerView

Comment: i tried your solution again, but it giving same problem. I added image in my question please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the bottom item is cut? if so, does the layout has any other constraint to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Also have you set the RV height to `0dp`?

Comment: I used your provide xml and paste in my studio. Yes I set to 0 dp.

Comment: Can you remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreScroll"` just in case; but it generally works in mine the entire list shows without cut

Comment: Also add `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to the RV probably enforce it

Comment: @vivekmodi Do you still have a problem here?

Comment: no all good. Thanks