# RecyclerView in scrollview cut last items

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have fragment with 2 RecyclerView.
I get some data from api and add it for `RecyclerView`s in `ArrayList`s, then notify view that data was changed. For some reason, the last element(s) of the `RecyclerView`s is getting cut-off. When i get 8 object - RVs show only 5 of them. On small screens even less. I am disable RVs scrolling, and want use one `ScrollView` for all fragment content.

This is the XML of the fragment:s

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.view.MainFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/onDutyMainRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/margin_m"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_m">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/requestTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sfprotext_semibold"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/on_duty_main_subtitle_font_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_liver"
                    android:text="Requests"
                    tools:text="Requests"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/showAllRequestsButton"
                    style="@style/ShowAllButtonDark"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/requestTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/requestTitle"
                    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
                    android:text="Show All"
                    tools:text="Show All" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/requestsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/on_duty_recycler_view_margin_top"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/requestTitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/groupTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sfprotext_semibold"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_liver"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/on_duty_main_subtitle_font_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_m"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/requestsRecyclerView"
                    android:text="Groups"
                    tools:text="Groups" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/groupsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/on_duty_recycler_view_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/groupTitle" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I try found solution in other question like that, but nothing helped me.
For examle, i tryed some solution from [RecyclerView is cutting off the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item)

Comment: Try `layout_height = 0dp` for RececlerView

Comment: @Ahmn21 It does not help

Comment: You are having recyclerview inside scroll view that might be the problem. 1. Try to set nestedscrollingEnabled false to recycler view. 2. Try to constraint the bottom recyclerview to the bottom of the parent. 3. try replacing scrollview with nestedScrollView.

Comment: It is not recommended to put a `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView`. It will defeat the purpose of "Recycle" in the `RecyclerView`. For your issue, try setting `android:layout_height` of `ScrollView` to `math_parent`.

Comment: @Manohar
i try your 2 and 3 advices and it helped me. Thanks a lot